# Perl LWP:Simple Get URL String Varilable

Tags: perl, url, get

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use LWP::Simple;
   use warnings;
   $content = 0;
   $find = "webvis.edgesuite.net";
   open (HOSTLIST,"lists.hosts");
   @hosts = <HOSTLIST>;
   foreach $host(@hosts) {
   $results = `nslookup www.$host`;
   my $pos = index($results, $find);
   if ($pos > -1 )
   {
   my $url = "http://www.$host";
   $content = get ($url);
   print $content;
   my $pos1 = index($content, $url);
   if($pos1 > -1) {
    print "Content Match\n";
   } else {
    print "No Content Match\n";
   }
   $count++;
   chomp ($host);
   print "$count www.$host\n";

   }
   }
   close (HOSTLIST);
   exit($errorcode);
```

Using the code above, I always get the following error:

> IO::Socket::INET: Bad hostname 'www.test.com

**If change the $url to:**

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com';
```

I get the content retrieval from the page.

So my question is how do I pass in a string variable to the get attribute so it doesn't produce
the bad hostname error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That works fine for me as written.  Try adding "use strict; use warnings;" to see if anything pops up.  May be an extra character in there somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're not reading $host from input? The code you have posted works fine for me.

Comment: If you change `print $url;` to `print "[", $url, "]\n";`
what output do you get?

Comment: I do read in a list of hosts from a file: open (HOSTLIST,"lists.hosts");
@hosts = <HOSTLIST>;
foreach $host(@hosts)

Comment: I actually modified the code above to make more sense

Answer (score 0):

When you read in the hosts from `<HOSTLIST>`, each line (except possibly the last) will have a newline at the end of it which does not belong in a domain name and thus has to be explicitly removed with the `chomp` function before trying to do anything important.